# Splitting and accessing strings in C

Tags: c, string, strtok

I am new to C and I am trying to pass arguments to my program like

```
program_name -param1=something -param2=somethingelse
```

Then in my program I want to loop through the arguments and split them on the "=" and print the two parts back to the command line.  Here is what I have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    char parampart;
    char paramvalue;
    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        parampart = strtok(argv[i], "=");
        paramvalue = strtok(NULL, "=");
        printf("parampart: %s paramvalue %s", parampart, paramvalue);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting errors because the variables parampart and paramvalues are pointers but I'm not sure how to use the pointers to get the string values.

Comment: strtok returns a char * not a char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strtok()` returns pointer, so you have to declare `parampart` and `paramvalue` as pointers, like

```
char *parampart;
char *paramvalue;
```

the rest of your code is correct.

Comment: Hah, I didn't even see that. Yeah, that's also a problem (unless you're on an 8-bit machine ;-)).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Linux you can use [getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt). it make life easier

Comment: Getopt will want "=" parameters to be --, not -. But that minor quibble depends on whether OP want to be able to parse parameters for use, or if the purpose of the exercise is to demonstrate using argc and argv. For use, getopt or getopt_long is clearly the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, although I don't want to limit myself to just Linux

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're assuming each argument will have a `=` in it. Which most of them do.... but not the zero'th one, which is `program_name`. You should start at arg 1, not arg 0, and you should check for a null return from the second `strtok` call, in case the user forgets the equals-sign.

Of course, as @MOHAMED mentioned, this is a job for getopt.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good example from `man strtok`, you should call once befroe your loop:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <string.h>

   int

   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       char *str1, *str2, *token, *subtoken;
       char *saveptr1, *saveptr2;
       int j;

       if (argc != 4) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s string delim subdelim\n",
                   argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       for (j = 1, str1 = argv[1]; ; j++, str1 = NULL) {
           token = strtok_r(str1, argv[2], &saveptr1);
           if (token == NULL)
               break;
           printf("%d: %s\n", j, token);

           for (str2 = token; ; str2 = NULL) {
               subtoken = strtok_r(str2, argv[3], &saveptr2);
               if (subtoken == NULL)
                   break;
               printf(" --> %s\n", subtoken);
           }
       }

       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

And according to `man getopt` :

```
#include <stdio.h>     /* for printf */
#include <stdlib.h>    /* for exit */
#include <getopt.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int c;
    int digit_optind = 0;

   while (1) {
        int this_option_optind = optind ? optind : 1;
        int option_index = 0;
        static struct option long_options[] = {
            {"add",     required_argument, 0,  0 },
            {"append",  no_argument,       0,  0 },
            {"delete",  required_argument, 0,  0 },
            {"verbose", no_argument,       0,  0 },
            {"create",  required_argument, 0, 'c'},
            {"file",    required_argument, 0,  0 },
            {0,         0,                 0,  0 }
        };

       c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "abc:d:012",
                 long_options, &option_index);
        if (c == -1)
            break;

       switch (c) {
        case 0:
            printf("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
            if (optarg)
                printf(" with arg %s", optarg);
            printf("\n");
            break;

       case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
            if (digit_optind != 0 && digit_optind != this_option_optind)
              printf("digits occur in two different argv-elements.\n");
            digit_optind = this_option_optind;
            printf("option %c\n", c);
            break;

       case 'a':
            printf("option a\n");
            break;

       case 'b':
            printf("option b\n");
            break;

       case 'c':
            printf("option c with value '%s'\n", optarg);
            break;

       case 'd':
            printf("option d with value '%s'\n", optarg);
            break;

       case '?':
            break;

       default:
            printf("?? getopt returned character code 0%o ??\n", c);
        }
    }

   if (optind < argc) {
        printf("non-option ARGV-elements: ");
        while (optind < argc)
            printf("%s ", argv[optind++]);
        printf("\n");
    }

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I suggest you set flag for each option and initilize them  according to behave your program.